# Thread pool stack security issue

Tags: security, multithreading, pool

In a naive implementation of a thread pool, can a piece of code that is being executed read the data left by some previous code on the stack (if it was running on the same thread instance)? Also, are there any other inherent security issues connected to thread pools?

Comment: Any specific language/runtime environment you are concerned about?

Comment: I'm mainly concerned about C++, so no managed code.

Answer (score 0):

Because all of the threads are running in the same process already, even if it *were* possible, it's not a security issue. Security boundaries are at the process level (well, technically, it does depend on your OS, but that's how it works in all the mainstream OSes).

Comment: That's not how, say, Java or the "managed" subset of .Net work.

Comment: Well, given that neither Java nor .NET gives you direct access to memory, it doesn't really matter, either.